# How to fetch the citation history of an articles using its DOIs in R?

Tags: r, cross-reference, citations, doi

I was wondering if it is possible to extract the citation history of articles using DOIs. I found the package `scholar` is helpful for getting the citation history of an individual from Google Scholar.

```
library(scholar)
get_citation_history(id="bg0BZ-QAAAAJ&hl")
  year cites
1 2017    25
2 2018    39
3 2019   114
4 2020   377
5 2021  1195
6 2022  2070
```

In my case, however, I do have only DOI and don't need the citation of an individual. I need the citation history of articles. For example, if I use `doi=10.1111/j.1365-2486.2008.01617.x` instead of `id`, I get an error. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The function `cr_works()` from the package `rcrossref` is also helpful for extracting the total citations of articles using their DOIs. However, as I said above, my question is about the yearly citation history of articles.  Thank you in advance for your help!